# Send Email with attachment using aws-sdk(Amazon SES) using nodejs

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-ses, aws-sdk

**Hello,
I am trying to send email with attachment ,using**

```
var params = {
        RawMessage: {
            From: "rajit.garg@daffodilsw.com",
            To: "rajit.garg@daffodilsw.com",
            Date: new Date(),
            Subject: "Hello",
            "Accept-Language": "en-US",
            "Content-Language": "en-US",
            "Content-Type": "text/plain", charset: "us-ascii",
            "Content-Transfer-Encoding": "quoted-printable",
            "MIME-Version": 1.0,
            Data: "Hello, I hope you are having a good day."
        },
        Destinations: [
            "rajit.garg@daffodilsw.com"
        ],
        Source: "rajit.garg@daffodilsw.com"
    };

    ses.sendRawEmail(params, function (err, data) {
        if (err) console.log("err>>" + err, err.stack); // an error occurred
        else     console.log("data>>>" + JSON.stringify(data));           // successful response
    });
```

but I am getting error

UnexpectedParameter: Unexpected key 'From' found in params.RawMessage
* UnexpectedParameter: Unexpected key 'To' found in params.RawMessage
* UnexpectedParameter: Unexpected key 'Date' found in params.RawMessage
* UnexpectedParameter: Unexpected key 'Subject' found in params.RawMessage
* UnexpectedParameter: Unexpected key 'Accept-Language' found in params.RawMessage
* UnexpectedParameter: Unexpected key 'Content-Language' found in params.RawMessage
* UnexpectedParameter: Unexpected key 'Content-Type' found in params.RawMessage
* UnexpectedParameter: Unexpected key 'charset' found in params.RawMessage
* UnexpectedParameter: Unexpected key 'Content-Transfer-Encoding' found in params.RawMessage
* UnexpectedParameter: Unexpected key 'MIME-Version' found in params.RawMessage

**I know I am not using the correct format of params , but i have not got the right format anywhere, please help me.....
Thanks in advance...**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[According to the documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/SES.html#sendRawEmail-property), the field `RawMessage` only contains a `Data` property and nothing else. The `Data` field contains an entire raw email message - including the headers and body (or bodies), all properly formatted (escaping, encoding) and delimited (proper number of newlines).

You might be looking for `sendEmail`, which allows you to set headers such as the 'To', 'From' and 'Subject' fields as `key-value` pairs.

Comment: Thanks RikkusRukkus, Can you please inform me in detail what the Data should contain, I have required to send Email with attachment and if possible containing multiple to, cc and bcc, and where I have to write the Subject, I have required to do this using Nodejs, Please help me, Thanks

Comment: `Data` should be a buffer with the *entire* email. That means you first set the headers, double newline, then the body. Just use [mailcomposer](https://github.com/andris9/mailcomposer). It makes your life easier. The output `mailcomposer.buildMessage` can probably be directly injected into `Data`.

Comment: Thanks RikkusRukkus, I have gain much with your link, but still have 2 prob, 1st I am not able to attach file from my system and 2nd I have required to write content to file and then read from file then give this to RawMessage-->data,  mailcomposer.addAttachment({     //this is not working 
    fileName: "serv.txt",
    filePath: "./cust-serv.txt"
});
mailcomposer.streamMessage();
mailcomposer.pipe(fs.createWriteStream("testnew.eml"));
fs.readFile('testnew.eml', function (err, data) {
    if (err) {..}
    params = {
        RawMessage: {
            Data: data
        },
        ............

Comment: Thanks you very much RikkusRukkus, I am able to send mail with attachment successfully, but i have one small problem now, i am using mailcomposer.setMessageOption , but through this my bcc is not working, and to , cc is working successfully, my previous problem is solved by using mailcomposer.buildMessage as you said, but i am using it wrongly previously, can you please help me for this also.

Comment: @RajitGarg Can you please post a working solution ? I tried but getting error `[InvalidParameterValue: Missing required header 'From'.]` even though I have added from field in the mailcomposer

Comment: @Rajit Garg - I'm also using the mailComposer and I'm trying to send a header "so I can receive it back on a bounce" ... But I cant receive back my custom headers, just the ones amazon defined. I have a enabled "include original headers" in SES.  Did you have any success on this before ?